# GCDAsyncUdpSocket dropping packets and creating lots of DISPATCH_WORKER_THREADs

Tags: cocoa-touch, debugging, grand-central-dispatch, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm building a multicast client with `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` and I'm facing a lot of packet loss.

I have monitored the server with Wireshark as well as captured the WiFi packets in the air with AirCap, and I'm sure the packets are transmitted properly. I also looked at the debug traces from the `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` library and I see that sometimes `socket4FDBytesAvailable:` is called with a large argument, like 4000, but when it reads the socket it read fewer bytes -- maybe 500 -- and that's where the packets are lost. I increased the socket buffer but that doesn't help.

Last, I noticed using Instruments' time profiler that, coincidence or not, each time I lose packets one new instance of a DISPATCH_WORKER_THREAD is created. Is this normal?